# Rodeo giving error on Excel import working in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, rodeo

Full disclosure: I am a total beginner when it comes to Python in particular and programming in general. So please bear with me.
Today I tried for the first time to play around some datasets on my own, outside of the sandboxed environment of online courses.
I downloaded both Anaconda and Rodeo (which somehow I feel more akin to than, say, Spyder or Jupyter).

Wrote down this code. It works in Spyder.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myexcel="C:/Users/myname/folder/subfolder/file.xlsx"
xl=pd.ExcelFile(myexcel)
mydf=xl.parse(0)
print(mydf.head())
```

However, if I try to run the same code in Rodeo I get the following error message. Here, I am showing just a part.

```
----> 4 xl=pd.ExcelFile(myexcel)
ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

I am getting that in Rodeo the script fail because it is missing the xlrd package, which admittedly after checking with `help("modules")` is not there. But I don't fully get the problem: if xlrd was quintessential to the correct execution of this code, then why doesn't it fail in Spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I know this doesn't answer your question, but I'd just like to point out that (to the best of my knowledge) Rodeo is not maintained anymore. The [last commit](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/commits/master) to its repo was almost a year and a half ago (a huge time for open source projects), and the [website](http://www.yhathq.com/) to the company that created it is not working anymore. So you should use other projects instead.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. The [website](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo) I downloaded it from makes no claim that it is not being maintained anymore. Thank you, this is probably the general reason causing my issue.